# Facing issue after update ember from 3.0.0 to 3.22.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, ember-cli

After updating ember from 3.0.0 to 3.22.0 using ember-cli-update and install npm packges. And finally hit ember s it throws the bellow error.

```
Build Error (SourceMapConcat)
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/folders/wm/w121z2bs7yngf13gc_qbsn_w0000gn/T/broccoli-51053YM0PSytfuMoE/out-881-broccoli_debug_debug_5_vendor_js/vendor/simple-module/lib/module.js'

Stack Trace and Error Report: /var/folders/wm/w121z2bs7yngf13gc_qbsn_w0000gn/T/error.dump.a86e097d39858aa6e4eacea11b04401c.log
```

Here is the full log file

```
ERROR Summary:

  - broccoliBuilderErrorStack: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/folders/wm/w121z2bs7yngf13gc_qbsn_w0000gn/T/broccoli-51053YM0PSytfuMoE/out-881-broccoli_debug_debug_5_vendor_js/vendor/simple-module/lib/module.js'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:439:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:344:35)
    at FSMerger.handleOperation (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pm-client/node_modules/fs-merger/dist/index.js:82:32)
    at SourceMap.addFile (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pm-client/node_modules/broccoli-concat/node_modules/fast-sourcemap-concat/lib/source-map.js:78:38)
    at headerFiles.forEach.file (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pm-client/node_modules/broccoli-concat/concat.js:203:18)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Concat.concat.end.concat (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pm-client/node_modules/broccoli-concat/concat.js:201:26)
    at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pm-client/node_modules/broccoli-concat/node_modules/fast-sourcemap-concat/lib/source-map.js:432:14
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at SourceMap.end (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pm-client/node_modules/broccoli-concat/node_modules/fast-sourcemap-concat/lib/source-map.js:419:12)
  - code: [undefined]
  - codeFrame: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/folders/wm/w121z2bs7yngf13gc_qbsn_w0000gn/T/broccoli-51053YM0PSytfuMoE/out-881-broccoli_debug_debug_5_vendor_js/vendor/simple-module/lib/module.js'
  - errorMessage: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/folders/wm/w121z2bs7yngf13gc_qbsn_w0000gn/T/broccoli-51053YM0PSytfuMoE/out-881-broccoli_debug_debug_5_vendor_js/vendor/simple-module/lib/module.js'
        at SourceMapConcat (Package /assets/vendor.js)
-~- created here: -~-
    at new Plugin (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pm-client/node_modules/broccoli-concat/node_modules/broccoli-plugin/dist/index.js:45:33)
    at new Concat (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pm-client/node_modules/broccoli-concat/concat.js:28:5)
    at module.exports (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pm-client/node_modules/broccoli-concat/index.js:28:10)
    at importPaths.map (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pm-client/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/default-packager.js:1312:14)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at DefaultPackager.packageVendorJs (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pm-client/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/default-packager.js:1306:35)
    at DefaultPackager.packageJavascript (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pm-client/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/default-packager.js:1182:27)
    at EmberApp._legacyPackage (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pm-client/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:1613:48)
    at EmberApp.toTree (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pm-client/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:1659:27)
    at module.exports (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pm-client/ember-cli-build.js:30:14)
-~- (end) -~-
  - errorType: Build Error
  - location:
    - column: [undefined]
    - file: [undefined]
    - line: [undefined]
    - treeDir: [undefined]
  - message: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/folders/wm/w121z2bs7yngf13gc_qbsn_w0000gn/T/broccoli-51053YM0PSytfuMoE/out-881-broccoli_debug_debug_5_vendor_js/vendor/simple-module/lib/module.js'
        at SourceMapConcat (Package /assets/vendor.js)
-~- created here: -~-
    at new Plugin (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pm-client/node_modules/broccoli-concat/node_modules/broccoli-plugin/dist/index.js:45:33)
    at new Concat (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pm-client/node_modules/broccoli-concat/concat.js:28:5)
    at module.exports (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pm-client/node_modules/broccoli-concat/index.js:28:10)
    at importPaths.map (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pm-client/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/default-packager.js:1312:14)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at DefaultPackager.packageVendorJs (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pm-client/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/default-packager.js:1306:35)
    at DefaultPackager.packageJavascript (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pm-client/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/default-packager.js:1182:27)
    at EmberApp._legacyPackage (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pm-client/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:1613:48)
    at EmberApp.toTree (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pm-client/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:1659:27)
    at module.exports (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pm-client/ember-cli-build.js:30:14)
-~- (end) -~-
  - name: Error
  - nodeAnnotation: Package /assets/vendor.js
  - nodeName: SourceMapConcat
  - originalErrorMessage: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/folders/wm/w121z2bs7yngf13gc_qbsn_w0000gn/T/broccoli-51053YM0PSytfuMoE/out-881-broccoli_debug_debug_5_vendor_js/vendor/simple-module/lib/module.js'
  - stack: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/folders/wm/w121z2bs7yngf13gc_qbsn_w0000gn/T/broccoli-51053YM0PSytfuMoE/out-881-broccoli_debug_debug_5_vendor_js/vendor/simple-module/lib/module.js'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:439:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:344:35)
    at FSMerger.handleOperation (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pm-client/node_modules/fs-merger/dist/index.js:82:32)
    at SourceMap.addFile (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pm-client/node_modules/broccoli-concat/node_modules/fast-sourcemap-concat/lib/source-map.js:78:38)
    at headerFiles.forEach.file (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pm-client/node_modules/broccoli-concat/concat.js:203:18)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Concat.concat.end.concat (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pm-client/node_modules/broccoli-concat/concat.js:201:26)
    at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pm-client/node_modules/broccoli-concat/node_modules/fast-sourcemap-concat/lib/source-map.js:432:14
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at SourceMap.end (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pm-client/node_modules/broccoli-concat/node_modules/fast-sourcemap-concat/lib/source-map.js:419:12)

=================================================================================
```

Can anyone give me an answer why this is happening and how should I resolve this?

Comment: Have you already tried to remove the `node_modules` and run the `npm install` again? You can also try to remove the `package-lock.json` (if you have one) before run the  `npm install`, in order to update all sub-dependencies.

Comment: Yes, already tried this approach.

Comment: The ember community usually recommends bump from an LTS to  the next LTS until you get the latest version, in order to check deprecations and fix future incompatibilities. But since you already have jumped to the latest version, try to check where the `simple-module` is being used. I saw that the latest update was 4 years ago, so may be some incompatibility issue. Maybe you are importing it as a sub-dependency, in this case try to update the parent dependency.